# How do i find a word from user input in another variable?

Tags: python, enumerate

This is my code:

```
a = ('the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'a', 'mat')
for i,j in enumerate(a):
    data = (i, j)
    print (data) 
word = input('Type a word out of this sentence - \'The cat sat on a mat\' : ')
word = word.lower()
print(word.find(data))
```

This is my code, and basically, when a user types in a word from the sentence, i want to find the index position and word from `data`, then print it.
Please can you help me to do this very simply, as i am just a beginner. Thanks :) (Sorry if i haven't explained very well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying the wrong direction.

If you have a string and call `find` you search for another string in that string:

```
>>> 'Hello World'.find('World')
6
```

What you want is the other way around, find a string in a tuple. For that use
the `index` method of the tuple:

```
>>> ('a', 'b').index('a')
0
```

This raises a `ValueError` if the element is not inside the tuple. You could do something like this:

```
words = ('the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'a', 'mat')
word = input('Type a word')
try:
    print(words.index(word.lower()))
except ValueError:
    print('Word not in words')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `a.index(word)` instead of `word.find(data)`. You just need to find `word` in `a`, and you don't need your for loop because all it does is keep reassigning `data`.

Your final result would look something like this:

```
a = ('the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'a', 'mat')
word = input('Type a word out of this sentence - \'The cat sat on a mat\' : ').lower()
print(a.index(word))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the index of `a` where `word` occurs, you need to change `word.find(data)` to `a.index(word))`.

This will throw a `ValueError` if the word is not in `a`, which you could catch:

```
try:
    print(a.index(word))
except ValueError:
    print('word not found')
```

Comment: so i don't need the enumerate and data bit?

Comment: @ClareJordan not at all

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need your loop because all it does is just assign the last element of your tuple to data.

So, you need to do something like this:

```
a = ('the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'a', 'mat') # You can call it data
word = input('Type a word out of this sentence - \'The cat sat on a mat\' : ')
word = word.lower()
try:
    print(a.index(data))
except ValueError:
    print('word not found')
```